# aws cognito user get id token android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to get the current logged in user's id token for aws cognito in android.

I found this example:
session.getIdToken().getJWTToken()
where session is a CognitoUserSession object

I can't seem to figure out a way to get the current cognitousersession after the login call has been made.

I'm using the default authenticator activity from the notes tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/tutorial-android-aws-mobile-notes-auth.html

It says that the tokens are stored in the shared preferences, but I can't figure out how to retrieve them on future activities so that I can make calls to the api gateway using the id token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS Android SDK will return the JWT token without a network call when the token is not/will not expire.

The threshold for when a token should be refreshed can be set with the `CognitoIdentityProviderClientConfig.setRefreshThreshold(long)` method.

If you are stil curious how to retrieve the token yourself, then the code can be found in `readCachedTokens()` method
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoidentityprovider/CognitoUser.java#L2116

Comment: Thank you donkon, that link was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody has answered yet, this might help you out, **be aware this is JS code**:

This is my routine to receive the session from an already logged in user. 
after this, i'm able to access tokens.

```
  var user_data = {
    UserPoolId: AWSConfiguration.UserPoolId,
    ClientId: AWSConfiguration.ClientAppId
  };

  var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(user_data);

  if (userPool.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    userPool.getCurrentUser().getSession(function (err, session) {
      if (err) {
        window.location.href = "login.html";
      }
      var user_params = {
        IdentityPoolId: AWSConfiguration.IdPoolId,
        Logins: {
          'cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_XXX':session.idToken.jwtToken
        }
      };
      AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(user_params);
      AWS.config.region = AWSConfiguration.region;

      AWS.config.credentials.refresh((error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } 
        else {
          user_is_authenticated();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: the CurrentUser.getSession for the android sdk makes a network call to get the tokens, which I am trying to avoid. I need a way to retrieve the stored tokens from the shared preferences.